# Including a link in a text field in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a lightbox jquery script to display some text when you click on an image. I'm very new to jquery, so i'm going in blindly - but i've managed to find the text section i want to edit, only I want to add a link in that space but am having trouble incorporating it.

I want to add the link where I have written "Inquire about these items". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
(function () {
    var b, d, c;
    b = jQuery;
    c = (function () {
        function b() {
            this.fadeDuration = 200;
            this.fitImagesInViewport = true;
            this.resizeDuration = 700;
            this.showImageNumberLabel = true;
            this.wrapAround = false
        }
        b.prototype.albumLabel = function (b, c) {
            return "Inquire about these items "
        };
        return b
    })();
    d = (function () {
        function c(b) {
            this.options = b;
            this.album = [];
            this.currentImageIndex = void 0;
            this.init()
        }
        c.prototype.init = function () {
            this.enable();
            return this.build
```

Comment: #1. Why are you assigning jQuery to b?. 
#2. Why are you using single letter function names? Can you write more descriptive names indicating what those functions do so we can understand the intent of those functions?
#3. This is not the complete set of the JavaScript. It's also already a lot. Maybe just leave the bits relevant to the specific question.

Comment: Hey - to be completely honest, I'm not sure what these functions are doing I just managed fo find a place where I could add text and it can be seen when you click on the image in the lightbox container. The main thing I need is simply to add a link where the "Inquire about these items" text is...

Answer (score 0):

You might just need some HTML. Make a link like that

```
Inquire about <a href=\"http://my-link.com\">there</a> items
```

This might work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to just add a link as you would normally but the lightbox function stops working... So I'm gussing I need to write it out in a different format that the jquery recognises?

Comment: placing some HTML in the `return` line should not make the lightbox stop working. What happens exactly?

Comment: When i add a link in the retern space the image i click doesn't appear in a lightbox - it just links through to just the image file...

Comment: This means the javascript failed. I think that's because of the code I gave you: I did not escaped the quotes. See the updated proposed return code.

Comment: I used the updated code which allowed the javascript to work but because of th "/" the link doesn't actually work now... Is there some sort of code that helps the script allow a link in this space?? Thanks for your help...